# Can't apt-get anything

Tags: boot, apt

I'm trying to fix an almost full boot partition, but can't seem to get any apt-get action to run. Not sure how to fix this messy situation.

```
# apt-get upgrade
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree
Reading state information... Done
You might want to run 'apt-get -f install' to correct these.
The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 libssl-dev : Depends: libssl1.0.0 (= 1.0.1-4ubuntu5.14) but 1.0.1-4ubuntu5.17 is installed
E: Unmet dependencies. Try using -f.
#
# apt-get -f install
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree
Reading state information... Done
Correcting dependencies... Done
The following extra packages will be installed:
  libssl-dev
The following packages will be upgraded:
  libssl-dev
1 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 111 not upgraded.
1 not fully installed or removed.
Need to get 0 B/1,574 kB of archives.
After this operation, 1,024 B of additional disk space will be used.
Do you want to continue [Y/n]?
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of libssl-dev:
 libssl-dev depends on libssl1.0.0 (= 1.0.1-4ubuntu5.14); however:
  Version of libssl1.0.0 on system is 1.0.1-4ubuntu5.17.
dpkg: error processing libssl-dev (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
No apport report written because the error message indicates its a followup error from a previous failure.
                                                                                                          Errors were encountered while processing:
 libssl-dev
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
#
# df -h
Filesystem                  Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
/dev/mapper/DRAGONITE-root   61G  3.7G   55G   7% /
udev                        993M   12K  993M   1% /dev
tmpfs                       201M  296K  201M   1% /run
none                        5.0M     0  5.0M   0% /run/lock
none                       1002M     0 1002M   0% /run/shm
/dev/vda1                   228M  163M   53M  76% /boot
#
# apt-get -f autoremove
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree
Reading state information... Done
Correcting dependencies... Done
The following extra packages will be installed:
  libssl-dev
The following packages will be upgraded:
  libssl-dev
1 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 111 not upgraded.
1 not fully installed or removed.
Need to get 0 B/1,574 kB of archives.
After this operation, 1,024 B of additional disk space will be used.
Do you want to continue [Y/n]?
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of libssl-dev:
 libssl-dev depends on libssl1.0.0 (= 1.0.1-4ubuntu5.14); however:
  Version of libssl1.0.0 on system is 1.0.1-4ubuntu5.17.
dpkg: error processing libssl-dev (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
No apport report written because the error message indicates its a followup error from a previous failure.
                                                                                                          Errors were encountered while processing:
 libssl-dev
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

### Update:

Ran the following with error:

```
# sudo apt-get purge libssl-dev
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree
Reading state information... Done
You might want to run 'apt-get -f install' to correct these:
The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 php5-dev : Depends: libssl-dev but it is not going to be installed
E: Unmet dependencies. Try 'apt-get -f install' with no packages (or specify a solution).
```

Answer (score 1):

Run the following commands to fix the problem:

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get purge libssl-dev
```

Take note of what packages are to be uninstalled. If the output lists 13 packages to uninstall, you can re-install everything using the following command. Otherwise, copy and paste each line, one-by-one after this command to reinstall everything.

```
sudo apt-get install --reinstall libroot-core-dev libssl1.0.0 libssl-dev
```

Again, that command will reinstall all 13 packages.

I don't know your situation but it may be wise to run the command:

```
sudo apt-get dist-upgrade
```

*However*, this command make changes to your system so you should refrain from that command until you have finished any important projects that may be affected by system changes!

Comment: Added the (unfortunate) result to my original post.