# I can't apt-upgrade,purge or install anything ubuntu 14.04

Tags: 14.04, apt, upgrade, package-management, purge

I am able to do apt-get update but I can't upgrade, install or purge. I am getting the following error:

```
libc-devv-bin: Depends: libc6 (<2.20) but 2.24-9 is to be installed
libc-l10n: Breaks: locales (< 2.21-1) but 2.12+git20120306-12.1 is to be installed 
libc6:i386 : Breaks: locales(<2.24) but 2.12+git20120306-12.1 is to be installed
libc6-dbg: Depends:libc6 (=2.19-0ubuntu6.9)  but 2.24-9 is to be installed
libc6-dev: Depends:libc6 (=2.19-0ubuntu6.9)  but 2.24-9 is to be installed
nodejs-dev: Depends:libssl-dev(>=1.0.0.0g) but it is not going to be installed

E: Unmet dependencies. Try apt-get -f install with no packages
```

I have tried most of the solutions such as:
[here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/527724/cant-apt-get-anything) or [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/749076/installed-wrong-libc6-dev-version)

But none of them is working.

Comment: What does `sudo apt-get -f install` do?

Comment: libc6 2.19-0ubuntu6.9 was in 14.04 (since replaced by 6.11). libc6 2.24-9 was never in Ubuntu, though a related version is in 17.04. You seem to have unwisely added a software source that provides software **incompatible** with 14.04. Uninstall ALL software from that source, and delete the source.

Comment: @Terrance apt-get -f install produces the same result

Comment: @user535733 it was katoolin which I deleted already. But I still have the same problem

Comment: Then you likely have not removed ALL software from that source.